# Why isn't my setup.py long description showing on pypi?

Tags: python, setuptools, restructuredtext, pypi

Trying to upload a package to pypi and it's all working except my long_description. It's meant to read through my README.rst but it is just blank on pypi. docutils rst2html isn't throwing any errors, setup.py --long-description prints out my readme, setup.py -check isn't producing errors either.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptocli

Setup.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages


with open('README.rst') as f:
    readme = f.read()

with open('LICENSE') as f:
    license = f.read()

setup(
    name='cryptocli',
    version='0.1.3',
    description='CLI to query cryptocurrency value',
    long_description=readme,
    author='huwwp',
    author_email='hpigott@gmail.com',
    url='https://github.com/huwwp/cryptocli',
    license=license,
    keywords='crypto cli query cryptocurrency bitcoin',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs')),
    install_requires=['requests'],
    py_modules=['cryptocli'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['cryptocli = cryptocli:main'],
    }
)
```

README.rst:

```
cryptocli
=========

Command line interface for querying current value of cryptocurrenies in
given fiat.

Usage
-----

Simple query

.. code:: bash

    cryptocli BTC
    2332.1

Accepts a comma seperated list of coins

.. code:: bash

    cryptocli BTC,ETH,XMR
    2404.39
    218.53
    40

Query with conversion to a given currency.

.. code:: bash

    cryptocli BTC,ETH,XMR -c JPY
    269731.76
    24712.42
    4563.86

Query with conversion and outputting a formatted string

.. code:: bash

    cryptocli BTC,ETH,XMR -c JPY -f
    BTCJPY:269679.75
    ETHJPY:24718.85
    XMRJPY:4562.29

Credits
-------

Uses the cryptocompare.com API

Tipjar
------

BTC: 15wNW29q7XAEbC8yus49CWvt91JkhcdkoW

Disclosure
----------

I am not liable for the accuracy of this program’s output nor actions
performed based upon it.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `license` argument is for supplying the name of the software license you're using (e.g., `'MIT'` or `'GPLv2'`), not for supplying the entire text of the license.  Apparently, whatever version of setuptools you used to build your sdist couldn't handle a multi-line license, as the `PKG-INFO` file in the sdist looks like this:

```
Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: cryptocli
Version: 0.1.3
Summary: CLI to query cryptocurrency value
Home-page: https://github.com/huwwp/cryptocli
Author: huwwp
Author-email: hpigott@gmail.com
License: MIT License

Copyright (c) 2017 huwwp

Permission is hereby granted, ...

Description: cryptocli
        =========

        Command line interface for querying current value of cryptocurrenies in
        given fiat.
...
```

setuptools' failure to indent the license text causes all subsequent fields of the `PKG-INFO` (including the long description and keywords) to not be parsed, hence why they don't show up on PyPI.  You should just write `license='MIT'` in your `setup.py` instead.

(Incidentally, your `LICENSE` file is not automatically included in your sdist unless you list it in a `MANIFEST.in` file, and the absence of a `LICENSE` causes your `setup.py` to fail, so no one can currently install your package as-is!)